# IJCAD 2018でビューの前方クリップのオンオフ

Tags: .net, vb.net, ijcad

IJCAD2018でVB.NETを使用して開発をしています。

下記のソースコードにて、現在のビューに対して、前方クリップをオンオフしたり、クリップの距離を設定する関数を作ったのですが、これを呼ぶとエラーは出ませんが、画面に変化がありません。
処理後にGCAD側のビュー管理のダイアログで、前方クリップと距離の設定を見ても、処理が反映されていなかったです。
これの正しいやり方を教えていただけないでしょうか。

一方で、上記と同じようにGetCurrentViewで現在ビューを取得して、ビュー（ビューの中心やカメラの目標点）を編集して画面に更新を掛けることはできていますので、全く見当違いの書き方でもないような気がします。

---

コード：

カレントビューの前方クリップのオンオフや、クリップ距離の指定がうまくいきません。

```
    Private Sub SetFrontClipOnOf(ByVal blnEnabled As Boolean)
        Dim icdDoc As Document = IJCADApplication.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
        Using icdTrans As Transaction = icdDoc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction
            Using acView As ViewTableRecord = icdDoc.Editor.GetCurrentView

                acView.FrontClipEnabled = blnEnabled
                icdDoc.Editor.SetCurrentView(acView)

            End Using
            icdTrans.Commit()
        End Using
        icdDoc.Editor.UpdateScreen()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetFrontClipDist(byval dblDist as Double)
        Dim icdDoc As Document = IJCADApplication.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
        Using icdTrans As Transaction = icdDoc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction
            Using acView As ViewTableRecord = icdDoc.Editor.GetCurrentView

                acView.FrontClipDistance = dblDist
                icdDoc.Editor.SetCurrentView(acView)

            End Using
            icdTrans.Commit()
        End Using
        icdDoc.Editor.UpdateScreen()
    End Sub
```

一方、全く同じようにCurrentViewを取得して指定位置にズームし、カメラターゲットをズーム箇所に合わせる処理は、うまくできています。

```
        Public Sub ZoomRangeByAcView(CenPnt As Point3d, icdDoc As Document, ByVal dblRad As Double)

            Using icdTrans As Transaction = icdDoc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction
                Using acView As ViewTableRecord = icdDoc.Editor.GetCurrentView

                    acView.Target = CenPnt

                    Dim matWCS2DCS As Matrix3d
                    matWCS2DCS = Matrix3d.PlaneToWorld(acView.ViewDirection)
                    matWCS2DCS = Matrix3d.Displacement(acView.Target - Point3d.Origin) * matWCS2DCS
                    matWCS2DCS = Matrix3d.Rotation(-acView.ViewTwist, _
                                                   acView.ViewDirection, _
                                                   acView.Target) * matWCS2DCS
                    matWCS2DCS = matWCS2DCS.Inverse()

                    Dim CenPntConv As Point3d = CenPnt.TransformBy(matWCS2DCS)
                    acView.CenterPoint = New Point2d(CenPntConv.X, CenPntConv.Y)

                    acView.Height = dblRad * 2
                    acView.Width = dblRad * 2

                    icdDoc.Editor.SetCurrentView(acView)

                End Using
                icdTrans.Commit()
            End Using
            icdDoc.Editor.UpdateScreen()

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

IJCADの.NET APIではViewTableRecordオブジェクトのFrontClipDistanceプロパティやFrontClipEnabledプロパティを変更しても反映されないようです。
ObjectARXのsetFrontClipDistanceメソッドを使用した場合は、問題なくクリップクリップ距離を変更することが出来たので、恐らく.NET APIの不具合だと思われます。
IJCADのサポートに、APIの不具合として報告した方が良いと思われます。